# Nest loop inside object. Why?

Tags: javascript, loops, data-structures, nested

```
const obj = {
  id: 1,
  nested: null
}

obj.nested = obj;

console.log(obj)
```

Why this code is created nested obj inside nested key and keeps going on? I know that array and object is pass By Reference in javascript.

Comment: Well, `obj.nested` points to `obj`. And `obj.nested` points to `obj`. And `obj.nested` points to `obj`… You get the idea…

Comment: _"Why this code is created..."_ - Ask the author of that snippet.

Comment: @Andreas I m the author of this snippet. I was doing some sort of programming and suddenly got bumped on this on my console :).

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee you can add your answer to one of the existing questions if it's relevant there and not already answered.

Comment: @freedomn-m Those questions are more on "Can" and this one was on "Why/How"

Comment: It points to itself -  [a circular reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference). It does not create nested objects. It is always the same object.

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee hence the "if relevant there" - you can vote for reopen on this question if you think it's different.